# Store multiple records at a time into database table and then check if any record had been lost or not

Tags: sql, linux, oracle, bash, shell

I am new to linux and Oracle SQL.
I would like to Store multiple records (of a pre-set length, say 800) at a time from a abc.csv file seperated by commas (contains huge no. of records, say a million) into database table and then check if any record had been lost or not.
If any record is lost in the process or not copied into database then retry to store whole lot again. 
I succeeded then move onto next lot else save which lot has not been stored into database in a seperate log file and continue to next lot.
The abc.csv has field columns as follows
record_no.,id,name,etc.,.....

Any ideas or sugestions are welcomed.

-Thanks in advance.

Comment: SQL*Loader is Oracle's high speed, bulk data loader. The .bad file would enable you to keep track of records which are rejected. The .log file will provide you with statistics about the load. Your control file will describe the nature of of the .csv file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Oracle SQL but in plain old MySQL you could just do `select count(*) from <tblName>` and see if the number matches what you expect to be in there after you do the inserts.

Note: this would only be beneficial if you knew the total amount of items being inserted into the table in total.

Comment: The only thing that concerns me with your answer is if OP is just assuming they will know the correct number of records. It's almost like he wants something to count the records in a CSV file, import/insert them into his Db, then compare the count of rows between the 2. However, if he/she will know the number of rows beforehand, your solution seems to work fine, in my opinion.